# Calling a static method of an abstract class in another class

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I have a class Employee

```
import javax.swing.*;
public abstract  class Employee {
    public static void  searchEmp(int id) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "done");
    }
}
```

Now I have another class test:

```
public class `test` {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     searchEmp(2);// here my programme give error
   }
}
```

I want to call the `searchEmp()` which is part of Employee from a class test but it gives an error. Please suggest any solution without inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

You have to call `Employee.searchEmp()`.

The static method `searchEmp()` is still a member of the class `Employee` and you must make a static call via its class.

Also the class `Employee` must be visible to the class `test`, otherwise you have to import it. I assume the two classes reside in the same package so this will not be a problem in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods and properties are bound to **class**. So you need to use `ClassName.methodName` or `ClassName.propertyName`.

```
Employee.searchEmp();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Test class doesnt have a static searchEmp(int) method, thus the error:

```
 searchEmp(2);// here my programme give error
```

should be

```
Employee.searchEmp(2);
```

static methods are called using `ClassName.staticMethod()`